# iterating through attribute tables (ArcGIS 10.1, Python)

Tags: python, r

I'm hoping to duplicate my techniques for looping through tables in R using python in the ArcGIS/arcpy framework.  Specifically, is there a practical way to loop through the rows of an attribute table using python and copy that data based on the values from previous table values?
For example, using R I would use code similar to the following to copy rows of data from one table that have unique values for a specific variable:

```
## table name:  data
## variable of interest:  variable
## new table:  new.data

for (i in 1:nrow(data))
{
    if (data$variable[i] != data$variable[i-1]) 
    {
        rbind(new.data,data[i,])
    }
}
```

If I've written the above code correctly then in words, this for-loop simply checks to see if the current value in a table is different from the previous value and adds all column values for that row to the new table if it is in fact a new value.  Any help with this thought process would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes to loop through values in table using arcpy you want to use a cursor.  Its been a while since I've used arcpy, but if I recall correctly the one you want is a search cursor.  In its simplest form this is what it would look like:

```
import arcpy
curObj = arcpy.SearchCursor(r"C:/shape.shp")
row = curObj.next()
while row:
    columnValue = row.getValue("columnName")
    row = curObj.next()
```

As of version 10 (i think) they introduced a data access cursor which is orders of magnitude faster.  Data access or DA cursors require you to declare what columns you want to have returned when you create the cursor.  Example:

```
import arcpy
columns = ['column1', 'something', 'someothercolumn']
curObj = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r"C:/somefile.shp", columns)
for row in curObj:
    print 'column1 is', row[0]
    print 'someothercolumn is', row[2]
```

Comment: Thanks you, these examples using the search cusor where helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To just get the unique values in a table in a field in arcpy:

```
import arcpy
table = "mytable"
field = "my_field"

# ArcGIS 10.0
unique_values = set(row.getValue(field) for row in iter(arcpy.SearchCursor(table).next, None))
# ArcGIS 10.1+
unique_values = {row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, field)}
```

Comment: I attempted to run this and received an error message:  invalid syntax.  Additionally,  im hoping to run through the table and select features using several conditional attribute criteria.

Comment: Are you in 10.0? This is only valid in 10.1.